# C++ and WMI: Pass a reference to a CIM class in the IWbemClassObject::Put method

Tags: c++, wmi

I'm trying to invoke a certain WMI method using C++: Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService::GetVirtualSystemThumbnailImage (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/virtual/getvirtualsystemthumbnailimage-msvm-virtualsystemmanagementservice).

The method itself requires three parameters: a reference to an instance of CIM_VirtualSystemSettingData, and two uint16s.

In C++, invoking a WMI method first requires you to obtain the the parameters for a method via IWbemClassObject::GetMethod and SpawnInstance; at this point, you can then start using the IWbemClassObject::Put method to begin filling out the parameters, i.e.:

```
CComVariant varCommand2;
varCommand2.vt = VT_BSTR;
varCommand2.bstrVal = _bstr_t("32");
hres = pClassInstance->Put(L"WidthPixels", 0, &varCommand2, CIM_UINT16);
```

This works fine. However, I am unable to find any documentation whatsoever with regard to passing an instance of a CIM class. The documentation on on IWbemClassObject::Put states:

> If pVal is to contain an embedded IWbemClassObject, the caller must call IWbemClassObject::QueryInterface for IID_IUnknown and place the resulting pointer in the VARIANT using a type of VT_UNKNOWN.

As such, this is what I am trying to do:

```
CComVariant varCommand;
varCommand.vt = VT_UNKNOWN;
vVirtualSystemSettingData[0].getClassInstance()->QueryInterface(IID_IUnknown, (void**)&varCommand); //getClassInstance returns a reference to the CComPtr that contains the VirtualSystemSettingData I want to use

hres = pClassInstance->Put(L"TargetSystem", 0, &varCommand, 0);
```

Unfortunately, I simply get a mismatch error, so I know I am not doing this correctly. Ergo, does anyone know how to pass references of CIM objects to the IWbemClassObject::Put method?

Kind regards!

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I'm having the very same problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your instance is already stored in the wmi repository you can use his path for creating reference.

For example:

```
VARIANT v;
VariantInit(&v);
V_VT(&v) = VT_BSTR;
V_BSTR(&v) = SysAllocString(L"{SOME_CLASS}.Name=\"{YOUR_INSTNACE_NAME}\"");

hres = pClassInstance->Put(L"TargetSystem", 0, &v, CIM_REFERENCE);
VariantClear(&v);
```

Access to instance from another namespace will be look like:

```
SysAllocString(L"\\\\.\\root\\{SOME_NAMESPACE}:{SOME_CLASS}.Name=\"{YOUR_INSTACE_NAME}\"")
```

And some full code example:
https://github.com/spmana/WMIWrapper/tree/master